# WMI EnableStatic = Type mismatch

Tags: vb.net

I run the following code:

```
Dim strComputer As String = "."
Dim objWMIService As Object = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Dim colNetAdapters As Object = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration " & "where IPEnabled=TRUE")
Dim ipAdd As String = "83.185.88.205"
Dim ipMask As String = "255.255.255.255"

     For Each objNetAdapter In colNetAdapters
                If objNetAdapter.Index = 458755 Then
                    objNetAdapter.EnableStatic(ipAdd, ipMask)
                End If
```

When I run this I get on row:
                        objNetAdapter.EnableStatic(ipAdd, ipMask)

"Type mismatch" error code

Any ideas why? The interface is a PPP interface established by the software that comes with the mobile broadband I use.

MSDN specifies:

uint32 EnableStatic(
  [in]  string IPAddress[],
  [in]  string SubnetMask[]
);

What does [in] signify and I believe I have to turn the variables into arrays somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your declarations to:

```
Dim ipAdd As String() = {"83.185.88.205"}
Dim ipMask As String() = {"255.255.255.255"}
```

**EDIT**

Looking more, every solution that I found that works has been using the `System.Management` managed namespace. Check out this code:

http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet2015.htm

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out tomorrow. Have a nice evening :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but found some issues and reworked the script to perform the subnetmask change that has bearing
I set a variable for the code to hold the ip address, gateway, etc... 
Hope this helps

```
' Script name: Subnet Mask Adjuster
' Date: April 2014
' 
' VBscript that will change the subnet mask
' Description
' Changing the subnet mask on a list of computers and logging the success per machine
' Script Requirements
' Script needs to record the current IP, Gateway, Gateway metric prior to changing the subnet mask
' When changing the subnet mask the script will once again reinstall the gathered information
' to ensure that the system is still addressable
'
' Access reqquirements
' Admin level access across all computers being targeted
'
' Script needs to be invoked as cscript.exe
' example: Cscript.exe CSNMIPBLOC.vbs "xx.xx.xx.xx"
' where the xx.xx.xx.xx is the ip address of the subnet

' global variables declaration
' --- Strings ---
Dim strCurrentDirectory, strDateTime, strInputFile
Dim strGateway, strGatewayMetric
Dim strSubnetMask
' --- File system objects ---
Dim objFSO, objLog, objTextFile
' --- Shell Objects ---
Dim objWSH
' --- File System Contants ---
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Const ForAppending = 8


' Create an instance of the file System object and shell object
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objWSH = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

' Get the path of the script
strCurrentDirectory = objWSH.CurrentDirectory

' retrieve the time for the log file name
strDatetime = funcGetDatetime 

' Get the path to the input file
strInputFile = strCurrentDirectory & "\Servers.txt"

' Create the log file  
Set objLog = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strCurrentDirectory & "\SubnetChanger_" & strDateTime & ".log", ForWriting) 

' Write the entry into the log file
subRprtProg "Subnet Mask Adjuster Script"
subRprtProg "Date/Time: " & strDateTime
subRprtProg "-------------------------------" 

' Open the input file
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strInputFile, ForReading)
subRprtProg "Opening input file " & strInputFile
subRprtProg "----------------------------------------------------"

' Read the contents of the file one line at a time and perform the function
Do Until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
    ' Read a line form the file and remove the spaces from the beginning and end
    strComputer = Trim(objTextFile.ReadLine)
    subRprtProg " "
    subRprtProg "Connecting to computer " & strComputer
    subRprtProg " "
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

    ' Enable Error Handling
    'On Error Resume Next
    ' Get the list on Network adapters from the Computer
    subRprtProg "Retrieving the Network adapters" 
    Set colNetAdapters = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration where IPEnabled=TRUE")

    strSubnetMask = Array("255.255.255.192")
    strSNMDisplay = strSubnetMask(i)
    subRprtProg "SubnetMask is: " & strSNMDisplay

    ' Go through the configured adaptors and nics 
    For Each objNetAdapter In colNetAdapters
        If Not IsNull (objNetAdapter.IPAddress) Then
            strIPAddress = objNetAdapter.IPAddress(i)
            objIPaddress = objNetAdapter.IPAddress
            subRprtProg "Current IP Address is: " & strIPAddress
            strGateway = objNetAdapter.DefaultIPGateway(i)
            objDefIPGW = objNetAdapter.DefaultIPGateway
            subRprtProg "Current Default IP Gateway: " & strGateway
            strGatewayMetric = objNetAdapter.GateWayCostMetric(i)
            objGWMetric = objNetAdapter.GateWayCostMetric
            subRprtProg "Current Gateway Metric: " & strGatewayMetric

            ' Setting the subnet and resetting IP, Gateway and GatewayMetric
            errEnable = objNetAdapter.EnableStatic(objIPaddress, strSubnetMask)
            subRprtProg "Setting IP Address to: " & strIPaddress
            subRprtProg "Setting Subnetmask to: " & strSNMDisplay
            errGateways = objNetAdapter.SetGateways(objDefIPGW, objGWMetric)
            subRprtProg "Setting IPGateway to: " & strGateway
            subRprtProg "Setting GateWay Metric to: " & strGatewaymetric
            Select Case errEnable
                Case 0
                subRprtProg "Successful completion, no reboot required."
                Case 1
                subRprtProg "Successful completion, reboot required."
                Case 64
                subRprtProg "Method not supported on this platform."
                Case 65
                subRprtProg "Unknown failure."
                Case 66
                subRprtProg "Invalid subnet mask."
                Case 67
                subRprtProg "An error occurred while processing an instance that was returned."
                Case 68
                subRprtProg "Invalid input parameter."
                Case 69
                subRprtProg "More than five gateways specified."
                Case 70
                subRprtProg "Invalid IP address."
                Case 71
                subRprtProg "Invalid gateway IP address."
                Case 72
                subRprtProg "An error occurred while accessing the registry for the requested information."
                Case 73
                subRprtProg "Invalid domain name."
                Case 74
                subRprtProg "Invalid host name."
                Case 75
                subRprtProg "No primary or secondary WINS server defined."
                Case 76
                subRprtProg "Invalid file."
                Case 77
                subRprtProg "Invalid system path."
                Case 78
                subRprtProg "File copy failed."
                Case 79
                subRprtProg "Invalid security parameter."
                Case 80
                subRprtProg "Unable to configure TCP/IP service."
                Case 81
                subRprtProg "Unable to configure DHCP service."
                Case 82
                subRprtProg "Unable to renew DHCP lease."
                Case 83
                subRprtProg "Unable to release DHCP lease."
                Case 84
                subRprtProg "IP not enabled on adapter."
                Case 85**************************** script *******************************
                subRprtProg "IPX not enabled on adapter."
                Case 86
                subRprtProg "Frame or network number bounds error."
                Case 87
                subRprtProg "Invalid frame type."
                Case 88
                subRprtProg "Invalid network number."
                Case 89
                subRprtProg "Duplicate network number."
                Case 90
                subRprtProg "Parameter out of bounds."
                Case 91
                subRprtProg "Access denied."
                Case 92
                subRprtProg "Out of memory."
                Case 93
                subRprtProg "Already exists."
                Case 94
                subRprtProg "Path, file, or object not found."
                Case 95
                subRprtProg "Unable to notify service."
                Case 96
                subRprtProg "Unable to notify DNS service."
                Case 97
                subRprtProg "Interface not configurable."
                Case 98
                subRprtProg "Not all DHCP leases could be released or renewed."
                Case 100
                subRprtProg "DHCP not enabled on adapter."
            End Select

        Else
            subRprtProg "No IP address detected on Adapter"
        End If
    Next 

    subRprtProg "Completed for computer " & strComputer
    subRprtProg "Moving to next computer"
    subRprtProg "----------------------------------------------------------------"

    ' Close Error Handling
    'On Error Goto 0
Loop

subRprtProg "Script completed at: " & Now()
subRprtProg "Script will now exit, see log files for details"

WScript.Quit

' Function to return the date and time in file name friendly format
' -----------------------------------------------------------------
Function funcGetDateTime
    ' Variable Declaration
    ' --- Integers ---
    Dim intYear, intMonth, intDay, intHour, intMin, intSec
    ' --- Strings ---
    Dim strFileName

    ' Get the date
    intYear = Year(Now())
    intMonth = Month(Now())
    intDay = Day(Now())

    ' Get the time
    intHour = Hour(Now()): If intHour < 10 Then intHour = "0" & intHour
    intMin = Minute(Now()): If intMin < 10 Then intMin = "0" & intMin
    intSec = Second(Now()): If intSec < 10 Then intSec = "0" & intSec

    ' Build the filename
    strFileName = intYear & intMonth & intDay & "_" & intHour & intMin & intSec

    ' Return the filename
    funcGetDateTime = strFileName
End Function

' SubRouotine to display in a cscript a message and 
' simultaneously write into the log file
' --------------------------------------------------- 
Sub subRprtProg(strMessage)
    WScript.Echo strMessage
    objLog.WriteLine strMessage
End Sub
```